# How can I add an element within the directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an input box that I am trying to add functionality to. I want to write a class directive to easily add an ability to any input box.  I want that when the user enters an '@', a box will pop up showing the options, using uib-typeahead. I cant figure out a way to display the box without making the original text box disappear, although ideally the box will pop up where the user is currently typing

```
<div class="medium-2">
   <label>Age:</label> 
</div>
<div class="medium-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control pop-up-variables" name="age" error-message="ageErrorMessage" required>
    </input>
</div>
```

The block I want to be able to add is this:

```
<input class="variable-dropdown" type="text" uib-typeahead="number as number for number in numbers | filter:$viewValue" ng-model="selectedAttribute" placeholder="Choose variable"> 
</input>
```

I don't want to return it as a template in the directive because I dont want to replace the block that the directive is on, but I don't know how to add it correctly to the DOM.

The simple JS looks like:

```
  app.directive('popUpVariables', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.on('keypress', function(event) {
            if (event.which === 64) {
                // This is where I want to show the second input
            }
        });
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: seems like all you need is a dropdown to show up, not another input

Comment: Use jQuery to add a select. You can use `$element` to find your directive's DOM element.

Comment: You don't need a second input,put `uib-typeahead` on the first, and make the numbers list empty when there is  no `@` in the input field.